# How to break execution of method in Groovy?

Tags: regex, string, methods, groovy

I have the code below and strange things hapened so I ***println*** something. When I passed to method **String** which matches the regex - printed :

```
---------->1
---------->2
```

How is this possible? How to return different return things?

```
def getInfo(String nameOfFile) {
    def matcher = nameOfFile =~ /(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)/
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        matcher.each { fullName, CN, FN, PN->
            println "---------->1"
            return [nameOfFile, CN, FN, PN]
        }
    }
    println "----------->2"
        return [nameOfFile]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just returns from the `Closure`, not the enclosing method

```
        return [nameOfFile, CN, FN, PN]
```

Depending on what it is you're trying to do (you don't give any example inputs), you probably want `findResult` instead of `each`:

```
def getInfo( String nameOfFile ) {
    def matcher = nameOfFile =~ /(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)/
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        matcher.findResult { fullName, CN, FN, PN->
            [nameOfFile, CN, FN, PN]
        }
    }
    else {
        [nameOfFile]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. You help me for the second time on this problem with returns and I just don't understand it as Java developer. Can you give URL to Groovy Documentation when this is described.

Comment: Hiya, no worries, it can be confusing at first when you come from Java. The formal [documentation is here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures). You can basically think of them as anonymous methods. If you imagine you had an interface which defines an `apply` method, then in Java you could define an anonymous class which overrides this method. Returning from this overridden  method wouldn't return from the enclosing method where it is defined, it would just return from the `apply` method. I'll look for some better definition and examples than this meandering definition ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *very crude* approximation of the Groovy code in Java (using 1.6):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

interface ClosureBlock {
    Object each(String... args);
}

public class Runner {    
    public List<String> getInfo(String nameOfFile) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(nameOfFile);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String fullName = matcher.group(0);
            String CN = matcher.group(1);
            String FN = matcher.group(2);
            String PN = matcher.group(3);

            ClosureBlock closure = new ClosureBlock() {
                public Object each(String... args) {
                    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String fullName = args[0];
                    String CN = args[1];
                    String FN = args[2];
                    String PN = args[3];

                    results.add(fullName);
                    results.add(CN);
                    results.add(FN);
                    results.add(PN);

                    // this return does not exit getInfo()
                    System.out.println("----------->1");
                    return results;
                }                
            };

            // each returns an Object but we didn't assign it
            closure.each(fullName, CN, FN, PN);
        }

        System.out.println("----------->2");
        results.add(nameOfFile);
        return results;
    }   

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Runner quick = new Runner();
        List<String> list = quick.getInfo(args[0]);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

The key points are:

- `Runner` defines an anonymous inner class with an each method. Calling return in the `each` method does not exit the `getInfo` method
- Even though the `each` method returns an `Object`, we don't assign it to anything so the `List<String>` in `getInfo` is unaffected.

The Java is ugly and complex. The Groovy code is much more elegant, but regarding your question, the Java code illustrates the idea.